# Visual C#: To check a hardware had connected to PC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm newbie of Visual C#.

I need to modify a pc based application which developed by Visual C# 2010. There is a button to open a "Chinese Handwriting Recognition System" software.

But I want to add a checking that the USB handwriting Pad had not connected to the PC or not. If not, it will prompt a message to remind to attached the USB pad.

How can I check the hardware had connected to PC or not ?

Thanks.
Joe

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this;

[How do I check whether a given USB device is plugged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048940/how-do-i-check-whether-a-given-usb-device-is-plugged-in)
Or possibly this might do what you need as well;

[C# Checking for presence of usb drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391167/c-checking-for-presence-of-usb-drive)